# FOSS Splunk alternative?

Tags: logging, real-time, splunk

What FOSS alternatives are there to splunk? From the splunk feature-set, at least the following should be available:

- real-time aggregation of logs from multiple sources into a single index
- real-time querying and graphing
- somewhat intelligent segregation of columns from log lines, and filtering based on that

Also some no-no's, mainly because of non-technical constraints:

- not based on HBase/Hadoop/Cassandra (well, basically Java)

If there is none currently available, what would be a good starting point to build one from?

Based on research so far, the option seems to be (scribed)[https://github.com/facebook/scribe] and (logstash)[http://logstash.net/]. Anything better that I'm missing out?

Answer (score 4):

Look at [Graylog2](http://www.torch.sh) or at [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/). Both based on elastic search, booth are Open Source. Graylog2 is under heavy development. Graylog2 is Java, now. Both are no real equivalent to SPLUNK, SPLUNK is multiple years ahead, but it's possible that these tools are also meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried this product myself, but [Alien Vault OSSIM 4.3](http://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/projects) seems to be very similar in functionality as Splunk. There is an open-source version and a paid version you can use.

Depending on what kind of log you want to feed it you will need the Clearcutter Log Sample Analyzer, also found on their site, to interpret the data.